# How do I get zsh completion to match from the middle of a filename ignoring case?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I am having difficulty getting zsh to autocomplete the way that I would like it to. Ideally, I would like type some string (that could be a single character), and after hitting tab, get a list of every file and directory that has that string in it, ignoring case. I thought my current configuration should do that, but it fails on a few file names. Here is what I am using:

`zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z} r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'`

The files that it fails on match `*a[0-9]+b[0-9]+*`. I would like to be able to type `b` and hit tab, and see all files that would match that regex. However, my current configuration displays no results.

For example, if I have a directory like this:

```
$ ls
x-a5b8.y
x.y-a111b82_z
x y.a0b44-z
```

Typing something and hitting tab should give the following results

```
$ b[tab]
x-a5b8.y
x.y-a111b82_z
x y.a0b44-z

$ b8[tab]
x-a5b8.y
x.y-a111b82_z
```

I looked at the [docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Matching-Control) for Completion Matching Control, but I was unable to figure out what specifically I need to do. If possible, I would love to use something like [regexr](https://regexr.com/) to see what patterns match what in real time.

Can anyone help me either find a pattern that works for my specifications, or to help me understand the pattern matching system?

I am using Oh My Zsh, but I don't think that affects this issue, as I have a file that modifies zstyle in the `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom` directory, and the output of `zstyle` has rules I specified for matcher-list.